# Iterate Java List in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, list, loops

I get a List from Java to javascript in AJAX response.
So i have to iterate the List of Beans and display each Bean as a record in the table.
Eg;

> [[prop1=value1,prop2=value2],[prop3=value3,prop4=value4],[prop5=value5,prop6=value6]]

After iterating list it must display as follows.

> value1 value2
>      value3 value4
>     value5 value6

It is having complexity in iterating the list in javascript.
I don't know how to iterate in javascript..
Any idea or response is highly Appreciated :-)

Comment: This would be 1,000x easier if you could get your Java code to emit JSON. As I don't know Java, the best I can do is point you [to Google](http://www.google.com/?q=emit+json+in+java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the data are in proper JSON format.

When you can convert it to javascript object. If you are using JQuery you can do,

`jQuery.parseJSON( jsonString );`

Then you can loop it like a normat Javacript array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {
    alert(myStringArray[i]);
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a string, so you will have to loop over it using string functions. I recommend using a regular expression, with which you can extract values based on certain patterns.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for an introduction and more information.